# JDBC Query Times & Performance

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, jdbc

I was wondering if anybody has seen/used a JDBC database performance software?  Basically I am trying to compare query times across MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, Hadoop, and a data virtualization solution all through JDBC access.  Since they have the same datasets(imported csv files into the db's), I wanted to compare access in time (milliseconds) from just JDBC, or through the data virtualiztion solution.

I have read about JMeter, but I'm not sure if this is the best alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: I think performance might be more closely related to the RDBMS than to JDBC. I have used MySQL and Postgres, and (in my personal experience), MySQL is faster (specifically, when using the MyISAM engine)... but it all depends on the specific needs you have

Comment: Barranka, Good point thanks for your input.  I do agree with you MySQL is definitely faster.  Basically we just want to see the query times.  So if I submit "Select Count(*) from oracleDB/Postgres/MySQL/Hadoop", I would like to see the amount of time it took to perform the query on each source.  Thank you for your point of view, i didn't think of things that way, good thoughts!

Comment: Most of the RDBMS would perform on par. Any performance gain would be marginal. I suggest the focus should be on query optimization, correct use of indexes, transactions (different isolation strategies) etc. IMHO that has much more scope for improving application performance. You could however leverage ORM technologies (like Hibernate's caching mechanism) to gain advantage over plain JDBC.

Comment: Thanks for your input Ravi, I appreciate it.  I think I should have been clearer in my question, basically I want to see the performance times of oracle/postgres/mysql/hadoop compared to accessing them through a data virtualization solution(TEIID).  Was wondering if there were any pieces of software that could easily give you the query time for each data source accessed through JDBC.

Comment: select count(*) is not going to be representative of the various RDBMSs as a whole, as PostgreSQL is notably poor prior to 9.2 due to the need to visit the table for data consistency purposes.

Comment: Do you have access to the code?  If yes, why not just add log statements with a query name, db name, start time and end time?  You could then load that into Excel and graph it.  That said, this is a potentially pointless exercise.  Let's say that Oracle is 50% slower than MySQL - are you sure you have Oracle tuned properly and you don't have one parameter set this is causing the difference?  Are you thinking of a single user test or are you going to scale users?  I would say pick the database that offers the best overall solution for your app.

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking at performance of the query or method level, I mean you want to see how much time its taking and all, then you can go ahead with profiling which will give you the basic idea for time consumption factor for each individual query is taking. From my experience DynaTrace is the one which used to give more accurate and more depth analysis which will help you a lot to analyze, in same time if you want to use any free version,then please go ahead to use JVMMonitor, which will not help you that much but yes this will give overview.